# Passing on error message if AUTOLOAD fails

Tags: perl

I am using `AUTOLOAD` to handle calls to some undefined subroutines.

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
    my $member = $AUTOLOAD;
    # ... do something if knowing how to handle '$member'        

    # otherwise ?
}
```

When calling a non-existent subroutine (say, `my_method`) on a package, Perl normally says something like

```
Can't locate object method "my_method" via package "MyPackage" 
at Package.pm line 99.
```

I want Perl to display this standard message in case I don't know how to handle the call to the subroutine `$member` in my implementation of `AUTOLOAD`.

How can I do that?

I found no special variable that might contain the appropriate message. Also the [Perl documentation on Autoloading](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) gives no hint for this problem.

**Remark:** I'd like to avoid rewriting the error message, but to use the standard message provided by Perl instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Perl first attempts to locate a method within the package, then its parent packages in `@ISA`, and finally `UNIVERSAL`. Next it repeats that process but searches for `AUTOLOAD` in lieu of the method name. The only way perl is going to raise an exception at the point of invocation is if no method can be found. If perl has invoked your `AUTOLOAD` sub, it's already past the point of *locating the method* and it can only die from within `AUTOLOAD`'s stack frame.

If you absolutely need to die *where* the method is invoked, your only option is to avoid `AUTOLOAD` and define all of your methods.

However, this will fake it, if only for the sake of appearance:

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
    my ($package, $method) = $AUTOLOAD =~ /^(.*)::([^:]*)/;
    die sprintf(qq{Can't locate object method "%s" via package "%s" at %s line %d.\n}, 
            $method, $package, (caller)[1,2]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, the message isn't available anywhere.  But you can use Carp to add the appropriate line and file:

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
    our $AUTOLOAD;
    my ($package,$method) = $AUTOLOAD=~/^(.*)::(.*)/s;
    use Carp ();
    local $Carp::CarpLevel = 1;
    Carp::croak( qq!Can't locate object method "$method" via package "$package"! );
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'd like to avoid rewriting the message myself. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: ok.  it seemed possible the part you wanted help with was the "at ... line ...", which my answer does.

Comment: Your "carp" should be "croak" since he wants the code to fail when the method can't be handled.